# Error Jaspersoft Studio Error preparing statement for executing the report query

Tags: jasper-reports

When I try the Preview Report, return this error

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error preparing statement for executing the report query : 

SELECT `accounts`.`name` AS `accounts_name` FROM `accounts` WHERE `accounts`.`id` NOT IN (SELECT `tasks`.`parent_id` FROM  `tasks` WHERE `tasks`.`date_modified` > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 3 OR 6 MONTH))


    at com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.preview.view.control.ReportControler.fillReport(ReportControler.java:467)
    at com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.preview.view.control.ReportControler.access$18(ReportControler.java:442)
    at com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.preview.view.control.ReportControler$4.run(ReportControler.java:334)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error preparing statement for executing the report query : 

SELECT `accounts`.`name` AS `accounts_name` FROM `accounts` WHERE `accounts`.`id` NOT IN (SELECT `tasks`.`parent_id` FROM  `tasks` WHERE `tasks`.`date_modified` > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 3 OR 6 MONTH))


    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRJdbcQueryExecuter.createStatement(JRJdbcQueryExecuter.java:377)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRJdbcQueryExecuter.createDatasource(JRJdbcQueryExecuter.java:196)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.createQueryDatasource(JRFillDataset.java:1119)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.initDatasource(JRFillDataset.java:691)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseReportFiller.setParameters(BaseReportFiller.java:434)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:508)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseFillHandle$ReportFill.run(BaseFillHandle.java:120)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: palabra desconocida: 
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRJdbcQueryExecuter.createStatement(JRJdbcQueryExecuter.java:267)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: palabra desconocida: 
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserBase.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserBase.readThis(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadSelect(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQuerySpecification(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadSimpleTable(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQueryPrimary(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQueryTerm(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQueryExpressionBody(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQueryExpression(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.compileCursorSpecification(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compilePart(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compileStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.compileStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.StatementManager.compile(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)
    ... 10 more
```

What's happen?

The Test database connection it's ok (I use org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver), the database is in Mysql(If I try the Mysql driver, error communication failure), the version the Jasper is the 6.0.0.

The code is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.0.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.0.0  -->
<!-- 2015-10-27T13:56:22 -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="CompanyReport" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="535" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="a5bf3d64-d6b6-48c5-9c1e-412341420f11">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="84"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="Canal4"/>
    <queryString language="SQL">
        <![CDATA[SELECT `accounts`.`name` AS `accounts_name` FROM `accounts` WHERE `accounts`.`id` NOT IN (SELECT `tasks`.`parent_id` FROM  `tasks` WHERE `tasks`.`date_modified` > DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 3 OR 6 MONTH))]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="accounts_name" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <background>
        <band/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band/>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="79">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="1" width="441" height="75" forecolor="#FFFFFF" backcolor="#000099" uuid="26217d12-c674-43a7-bc1a-bf78deeaec88"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="24"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Informe detallado de empresa]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="0" y="76" width="555" height="1" forecolor="#666666" uuid="fdffb19d-6028-475b-950b-e79e2b1f99c8"/>
            </line>
        </band>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band/>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="381">
            <rectangle>
                <reportElement x="1" y="4" width="554" height="24" forecolor="#CCFFFF" backcolor="#CCFFFF" uuid="0f212168-15c3-4f56-986f-459e65788377"/>
            </rectangle>
            <line>
                <reportElement positionType="FixRelativeToBottom" x="0" y="258" width="555" height="1" uuid="7ad8233c-4bbe-4ccf-b271-4346d742f303"/>
            </line>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement x="80" y="7" width="284" height="20" uuid="1e5b0494-848f-48c2-8e3f-71859e5d6049"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="11"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{accounts_name}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="6" width="70" height="21" forecolor="#006699" backcolor="#E6E6E6" uuid="95550a5a-8e1c-403d-8be1-cec0f685ec04"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                    <font size="11" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Empresa :]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="23">
            <textField>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="8" width="515" height="13" backcolor="#E6E6E6" uuid="6b37b78b-a8fe-497c-8266-7029bfa327e6"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Page "+$V{PAGE_NUMBER}+" of"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField evaluationTime="Report">
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="515" y="8" width="40" height="13" backcolor="#E6E6E6" uuid="95b2ed71-fa56-43af-bc36-44f93a377437"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[" " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField pattern="EEEEE dd MMMMM yyyy">
                <reportElement x="0" y="4" width="100" height="13" uuid="19ca911f-a36f-4549-b58f-866a11508e95"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new java.util.Date()]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="0" y="2" width="556" height="1" uuid="626fba8b-3b52-4e3a-a726-266aebe08c93"/>
            </line>
        </band>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: Did yuo check the query from *jrxml*?

Comment: What is a reason to use single quote in query?

Comment: I would try to configure the mysql driver (org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver) or the (com.mysql.jdbc.Driver), with jdbc url: jdbc:mysql://localhost/yourdb and correct credentials..

Comment: From the .jrxml doesn't work, and the reason for a use a single quote in query, I have 3 hours trying for this work....

Comment: Copy and past the query into mysql workbench, if it works its ok, then you just need to configure the driver correctly... the  org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver is as far as I have seen not the correct one, you need to configure the mysql driver

Comment: The Query is work perfectly.

Documentation for configure the mysql driver?

Comment: Is the server on localhost (on your machine?)

Answer (score 0):

The solution was comment the line in skip-networking the configure file of mysql, my.cnf

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if is the same case but I was deling with the same error for hours just to notice that I was closing the connection before sending it to the report